# How to do something repeatedly while a button is pressed?

Tags: android, button, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm developing a TV-Remote Simulator app in Android using a specific middleware (not of importance).

In the case of Volume Buttons (Volume+ and Volume-), what I'm trying to do is to send the "Volume Up" signal repeatedly while its button is pressed.

That's what I tried at last (code for one of the buttons, the other must be identical except for the names):

1. Declared a boolean variable

   ```
   boolean pressedUp = false;
   ```
2. Declared a inner class with the following AsyncTask:

   ```
   class SendVolumeUpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
           while(pressedUp) {
               SendVolumeUpSignal();
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Add the listener to the button:

   ```
   final Button buttonVolumeUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.volup);
   buttonVolumeUp.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           switch (event.getAction()) {

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

               if(pressedUp == false){
                   pressedUp = true;
                   new SendVolumeUpTask().execute();
               }

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

               pressedUp = false;

       }
           return true;
       }
   });
   ```

I've also tried with simple threads as in [Increment-Decrement counter while button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852360/increment-decrement-counter-while-button-is-pressed) but neither worked. The application works finely for the rest of the buttons (channels, etc.), but volume changing is completely ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add a break; at the end of the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: case. That means the line  pressedUp = false; gets executed even on that action. The correct thing to do would be:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        if(pressedUp == false){
            pressedUp = true;
            new SendVolumeUpTask().execute();
        }
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        pressedUp = false;

}
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now signals are sent. However, it sends a lot of signals for a short pressing period. Perhaps a counter should work.

Comment: I would recommend having an interval between calls to SendVolumeUpSignal(); For example try this: `while(pressedUp) {
            SendVolumeUpSignal(); Thread.sleep(100);}`

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered

- Starting your repititive task on the [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) event
- Stopping the task on the [onKeyUp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyUp%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)
  event ?

Comment: Aren't those methods for physical keys of the device? I meant tactile ones in my remote App

Comment: yeah, the name suggests so.. but they are not :-)